# find values in 3 arrays at the same point

Tags: matlab

I have an issue that I need help with. I have a data set; x,y,z, each of them is 10 rows long. I want to find the closest number in the table. That is, where is the minimum value where all the three are at the same row? My attempt:

```
[minval,minpos] = min( abs(xyz - repmat(point,length(xyz),1)) )
```

xyz is the 3x3 matrix with their own columns .

Comment: Can you show us an example dataset?

Comment: I didn’t have place for all of it, but here are the 7 first (in columns)
For x=
[6
6.00000000000000
6
5.99568915367126
5.98706793785095
5.97844743728638
5.96982693672180
5.96120619773865]


for y= [
7.31465506553650
7.32327580451965
7.33189654350281
7.50000000000000
7.50000000000000
7.50000000000000
7.50000000000000
7.50000000000000]


for z= [
0.125000000000000
0.125000000000000
0.125000000000000
0.125000000000000
0.125000000000000
0.125000000000000
0.125000000000000
0.125000000000000]

Comment: I can't edit it so that they are in columns, sorry!

Comment: You should add clarifications as edits to your original question.

Comment: Also please provide the expected output. I'm having a hard time understanding what it is you're after.

Answer (score 0):

I assume these are coordinates in a 3D space and you would like to know the point closest to the origin (0,0,0).

In that case you should do this:

```
[minval,minpos] = min( x.^2 +y.^2+z.^2 )
```